# How to get Itent.ACTION_SEND working for any file type

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the following snippet to open or share any file from device's storage (`MyFile` is my own class which extends `File` and should be considered as `File`. The flag `String` I'm passing is either `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` or `Intent_ACTION_SEND`):

```
    public void openOrShare(String flag, MyFile f){
    try {
        MimeTypeMap mmap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String type = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(f
                .getName());
        String ftype = mmap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(type);
        if (ftype == null)
            ftype = "*/*";
        Intent intent = new Intent(flag);
        Uri data = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.setDataAndType(data, ftype);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Tools.gimmeToast(
                getActivity(),
                "no application found to handle this file type",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While passing `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` everything works fine for any (also custom) types, the system creates a chooser and lists the apps, for well-known files it launches the correct `Activity` to handle the file immediately .

**The problem:** passing `Intent.ACTION_SEND` seems to be working halfway - it creates the chooser as well, however most apps (Dropbox and many more that I've tested with) just crash with an `NPE` when confirming the action. Testing with various email clients also failed: they don't crash like most of the other apps, but create a message and put the local `Uri` (like `//storage/.....`) in the `To` field (gmail) OR simply create a new empty message, ignoring the `Intent` data (yahoo! mail), while I expect them to attach the file to a new message.

**The question:** what am I doing wrong to share any file type?

**EDIT**

I figured out that it works if using `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));`, however there's an `ActivityNotFoundException` being caught when trying to share some specific files (like .dat). As far as I know, apps like Dropbox support adding any file types. Looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I finally figured that out. So here's the working solution which allows to share any type of data using any app*:

**Note: the below code actually also lists apps that might be not able to handle specific file types, those apps (at least they should) notify the user that the file type is not supported if this is the case*

```
    public void doShare(MyFile f) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        MimeTypeMap mmap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String type = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(f.getName());
        String ftype = mmap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(type);
        if (ftype == null)
            ftype = "*/*";
        intent.setType(ftype);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Tools.gimmeToast(getActivity(),
                "no application found to handle this file type",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the MIME Type of the file, then do not set it.

So I would try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(flag);
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(f);
String ftype = mmap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(type);
if (ftype != null) {
    intent.setDataAndType(data, ftype);
} else {
    intent.setData(data);
}
```

[setDataAndType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) needs data and explicit mime type (maybe */* is not).